# what does "mptbase: ioc0: RAID STATUS CHANGE for PhysDisk 1 id=8" mean?

Tags: linux

I received the following messages in `/var/log/message`:

```
Sep  6 04:23:30 localhost kernel: mptbase: ioc0: RAID STATUS CHANGE for PhysDisk 1 id=8
Sep  6 04:23:30 localhost kernel: mptbase: ioc0:   SMART data received, ASC/ASCQ = 5dh/00h
Sep  6 04:26:01 localhost kernel: mptbase: ioc0: RAID STATUS CHANGE for PhysDisk 1 id=8
Sep  6 04:26:01 localhost kernel: mptbase: ioc0:   SMART data received, ASC/ASCQ = 5dh/05h
```

This message is repeated frequently, and it has been going on for two weeks. But the server seems ok, I haven't noticed any service failure.

What does this messages mean?

Comment: you'd better ask it on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1):

So `5Dh` is for "Informational Exceptions".  The `05h` is "Access Times exceeding limits." which doesn't sound too worrisome unless performance is your main concern.  The `00h` seems to be a timeout, so I'm guessing the drive has been in use for a while.  If you want to be really proactive, go ahead and replace the drive.

### 5Dh reference

from [the bowels of googles cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:F6XTTxYwFZAJ:ftp://ftp.t10.org/t10/t10r/1999/r9907065.htm+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)

```
From: "Elliott, Robert (Hou)" <Robert.Elliott@COMPAQ.com>
To: "'t10@symbios.com'" <t10@aztec.co.lsil.com>
Subject: ASC/ASCQ 5Dh and SMART disk drives
Date: Tue, 6 Jul 1999 10:07:37 -0500 
Extracted-To: T10_Reflector

* From the T10 Reflector (t10@symbios.com), posted by:
* "Elliott, Robert (Hou)" <Robert.Elliott@COMPAQ.com>
*
ASC code 5Dh is used for Informational Exceptions.  Disk drives following
the "SMART" (non)standard use ASCQs from 10-7Fh to report detailed failure
prediction information.  However, SPC-2 Table C.1 only defines those ASCQs
for RBC devices.  RBC Table 18 defines the meaning of each code in that
region.

How should we make these codes legal for SBC devices?  Ralph doesn't want
to just add SBC to the list of standards that use those codes, since it
doesn't define their meaning.  A reader wouldn't know to refer to RBC for
the definitions.  The codes are too disk-specific for SPC-2 itself.

If an SBC-2 project is started, it could certainly go there.  Gene noted
that the table could be added to the ISO version of SBC, since that is
still open.


Background:
SPC-2 revision 11 lists these ASC/ASCQ assignments in its annex 
(table C.1):
5D 00 Failure Prediction Threshold Exceeded (all devices)
5D 01 Media Failure Prediction Threshold Exceeded (MMC-2, RBC)
5D 02 Logical Unit Failure Prediction Threshold Exceeded (MMC-2)
5D FF Failure Prediction Threshold Exceeded (False) (all devices)
5D nn Detailed Failure Prediction Information (nn=10h-7Fh)(RBC)

RBC defines the ASCQs in this manner:
    Value       Meaning
upper nibble:   
    0       General Hard Drive Failure 
    1h      Hardware impending failure
    2h      Controller impending failure
    3h      Data Channel impending failure
    4h      Servo impending failure
    5h      Spindle impending failure
    6h      Firmware impending failure
    7h      Reserved
    8h-Fh       Vendor-specific in SPC-2
lower nibble: 
        0       General Hard Drive Failure
        1h      Drive Error threshold exceeding limits.
        2h      Data Error Rate exceeding limits.
        3h      Seek Error Rate exceeding limits.
        4h      LBA reassignment exceeding limits.
        5h      Access Times exceeding limits.  
        6h      Start Unit Times exceeding limits.
        7h      Channel parametrics indicate impending failure
        8h      Controller detected impending failure.
        9h      Throughput performance
    Ah      Seek time performance
    Bh      Spin-up retry count
    Ch      Drive calibration retry count
    Dh-Eh       Reserved.
```